# I use : gtk-chtheme & obconf , each one has 1 theme selected, for gtk-2.0 and non-gtk-2.0 areas, but when I delete all other themes.. stuff breaks

Tags: gui, openbox, theme, gtk2

Based on my `obconf` I have "DiceBox" theme selected.
Based on my `gtk-chtheme`, I have "Shiki-JetBlack" selected.

Which means I can go into

```
/usr/share/themes/
```

and just delete everything except these two right?

I did just that and suddenly my scroll bar's color changed when I re-loaded Firefox and other programs.

Why?

What other theme am I making use of besides these 2 that I don't know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You removed some files that are needed. Because you deleted `/usr/share/themes/` and the given directory, contains `/usr/share/themes/Default` and Default contains the `gtk-2.0-key` and  `gtk-3.0` directories.